# Can I install Visual Studio Team Foundation Server on Windows Web Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am wondering whether or not I can install Visual Studio Team Foundation Server on Windows Web Server 2008 R2? This because that's the OS offered by my VPS provider.